# How to create a stub Python package for PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, stub

Let's say we have a builtin module `car`.

We have no autocomplete in PyCharm for it.

It has interface:

```py
def getState(id, optional_id = None):
    pass

def log(value):
    pass
```

So, end usage would be:

```py
import car


car.getState(5)
car.log('Test')
```

How to create a package and join it into PyCharm to make autocomplete work for a described interface?

If I created a package `car-stub` with `car.py` file, and installed it in the project, I will have to use code line `from car-stub import car`.

But how to make it in such a way it would not require code changes?
 The system would provide autocomplete for `import car`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. You need to create a stub package with methods (at least this solution working).

Create the following structure for your package:

```
/car-stabs
  __init__.py
setup.py
```

Where `car` is your package name to stub (the problem might be in naming if such package does exist).

`__init__.py` shall contain target interface methods.

```py
def getState(id, optional_id = ...): ...

def log(value): ...
```

(Or use "pass" like in the question for Python lower v3.5)

Now push the package normally to PyPi, and import it in your project and/or share with somebody who need it. =)